# Most efficient way to find the largest and smallest values entered? (C++)

Tags: c++, comparison

Here is how I did it, using a vector (Note: This is far from the most efficient way to solve this problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector<double>n;

    double val = 0;

    bool turkey = true;

    cout << "Please enter a positive number (max. 1,000,000)" << '\n';

    while(turkey){
        cin >> val;
        if (val >= 0 && val <= 1000000){

            n.push_back(val);

            sort(n.begin(), n.end());

            cout << n[0] << " is the smallest value so far" << '\n';
            cout << n[n.size()-1] << " is the largest value so far" << '\n';

        }
        else {
            turkey = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the most efficient way to find max and min values?

Also, is there any way to terminate this with a '|', considering the input is a double?

FYI: Question is from Programming Principles & Practice. I have solved the question; just looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: Imagine how you would do it with pencil and paper. I will run a thousand numbers past you, and all you have to do is report the largest and smallest...

Comment: Yes, you can do this by saving the min and max values as you go along.  No array or vector required.  If you already have them in a vector, sorting is a pretty bad solution unless you need it sorted for other reasons.  Just use [`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty trivial approach.

```
double value, minimum = -1.0, maximum = -2.0;  // note initialisation maximum < minimum
bool valid_input;

do
{
     std::cout << "Please enter a positive number (max. 1,000,000)" << '\n';
     if (!!(valid_input = ((std::cin >> value) && (value > 0.0 && value < 1E6))))
     {
         if (maximum < minimum)
             minimum = maximum = value;
         else if (value < minimum)
             minimum = value;
         else if (value > maximum)
             maximum = value;
     }
}
while (valid_input);
```

One feature of this is that the range checking on `value` is optional.  All the user needs to do is enter a non-numeric non-white character (then enter) and they can force the loop to exit (albeit subsequent code will need to clear the error condition of `std::cin` and read any pending input).

Comment: Thank you. Did you add the `!!` for your own amusement :)

Comment: It's a shorthand I use to indicate a condition being tested that has side effects.   It also (often) has the convenient effect of stopping compiler warnings due to an assignment being tested in an `if` statement such as `if (some_variable = some_expression)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be solved without vectors.
You only need two (three) variables

```
double min, max;  
bool first = true;
```

Then

```
while(turkey) { //turkey?
    cin >> val;
    if(first)
    {
        first = false;
        min = val;
        max = val;
    }
    if(val < min) min = val;
    if(val > max) max = val;
```

The thing with "first" is only one possibility. You could make a separate read before the loop (including check for "|"), or you could use the min/max possible double values, ...

About the "|": Read the input as string, check for "|", else parse it as double *after this check*.

Comment: Using `first` is kinda sloppy.  You can do away with it by initialising `min = DBL_MAX` and `max = -DBL_MAX` from `<cfloat>`.